# Dynamic Linq/Lambda Filtering

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I havea method that returns Expression to be used for dynamic filtering of records based on the clients needs, i have a problem in doing it, i want something like this

```
     public Expression<T> FilterCreator<T>(FilterCondition condition, string columnName, object value)
    {

        Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> query;

        // FilterCondition is an enum flag for conditions
        if(condition.Condition == ConditionFlags.EQUALS)
        {
            // here is the problem,
            // i want the emailAddress to be dynamic based on the passed columName parameter of the client 
            // and be able to cast its type of the value that was passed
            query = p => p.EmailAddress == (typeof(p.EmailAddress))value;

           //i want something like this
           // query = p => p.(columnName)=> (typeOf(p.(columnName)))value;

        }
        else if(condition.Condition == ConditionFlags.CONTAINS)
        {
             .....
        } 

        return query;

    }
```

any advise guys? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build an expression tree:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter<Customer>();
p = Expression.LambdaFunc<Customer, bool>(
    Expression.Call(typeof(object), "Equals", null, //non-generic
                    Expression.Property(param, columnName),
                    Expresssion.Constant(value)
    )
);
```

Comment: where is the == operator on that tree? how about expression for  the .Contains method of a string.

Comment: @dot: Nowhere; It calls `Object.Equals` instead.  This makes string equality work correctly (comparing by value).  You can also build expression trees that call other methods; see the documentation.

Comment: uh, i get it, so when i want to use Contains(), ill just call typeof(string) and call the method "Contains" ? thanks

Comment: No; `Contains` is an instance method, so you call it on an instance rather than a type.  `Expression.Call(Expression.Property(param, columnName), "Contains", null, Expresssion.Constant(value))`